# Salesforce JDBC driver connection in soapUI

Tags: jdbc, salesforce, soapui

We are trying to connect Salesforce through soapUI but getting below error, can someone help with detailed solution which is working. 
Got the Salesforce JDBC driver and connection string from https://github.com/ascendix/salesforce-jdbc

- Driver: `com.ascendix.jdbc.salesforce.ForceDriver`
- Connection string: `jdbc:ascendix:salesforce://;user=username;password=password`
- soapUI open source 5.4.0

Error:

> Can not get the connection for specified properties;
>        java.sql.SQLException: [LoginFault [ApiFault exceptionCode =
>        'INVALID_LOGIN' exceptionMessage = 'Username, password, or invalid
>        security token, or locked user.' extendedErrorDetails = '{[0]}']]

Comment: Just checking the obvious: are you sure the user name and password are valid? Do you have a way to verify them outside of soapUI?

Comment: @craigcaulfield, Yes they are valid, outside SoapUI we need to pass secret key post username and password. In SoapUI i have tried with secret key as well appending to password. Also tried to connect with session id instead of username and password looks like SoapUI accepts only username and password format, for session id it is not trowing any error.